# Will there be issues in importing a maven project using Eclipse (Windows > Ubuntu)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I've got a maven (Spring + Hibernate) project which was developed using Eclipse in Windows. I'm trying to import it into Eclipse (version Mars) in Ubuntu.

Will there be any configuration or dependency issues while importing it in Eclipse, from Windows to Ubuntu. If so what could be the best way to import in such scenarios.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee Couldn't run the project using Jetty, where as I was able to do it in Win; also had issues with surefire maven dependency.

Comment: Why should there be any issues if the project is purely written in Java?

Comment: When you say "project", do you mean the *maven* project or the *eclipse* project? I imagine the project by itself to be the *maven* project, but if any of eclipse's things are in it (`.classpath`, `project`, `.settings`, etc.) it'd be the *eclipse* project.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try it? That's why we have version control systems ;)

While importing I don't think there will be issues. But you will need to take care about file encodings and line endings.

When you correct line endings and file encodings you need to be aware that whatever uses hashes (Flyway for example) will need to recompute them.

For maximum compatibility don't import the eclipse project itself in ubuntu, import the maven project.